# ZF2 - Make onbootstrap events in one module supersede every other module

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I have a ZF2 module called "Browsercheck", when used with other modules, checks the user's browser and shows an "Unsupported Browser" page if the browser is not supported. The issue I am having is, that the following code which is onBootstrap of the "Browsercheck" is not taking the first preference when other modules encounter an exception or a 404 error. IT works otherwise.

How can I make sure this code executes for every event and supersede any other event? Ideally in ZF1, I use code like this in index.php.. but not sure how it should be in ZF2. Basically if the browser is not supported, it shouldn't matter whether it's a 404 or an exception. It should go ahead and render the unsupported browser page.

```
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
{   
    $sharedEvents = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager()->getSharedManager();
    $sharedEvents->attach('Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractController','dispatch',
    function($event)
    {
        $browser = new \BrowserCheck\Service\BrowserCheck();
        if (!$browser->isCompatible())
        {
            $viewModel = new \Zend\View\Model\ViewModel();
            $viewModel->setTerminal(true);

            $request = $event->getRequest();
            $response = $event->getResponse();


            $viewModel->setTemplate('browser-check/index/index.phtml');
            //Replace the entire view
            $event->setViewModel($viewModel);
            $event->stopPropagation();
            $response->setStatusCode(200);
            return $viewModel;
        }
    });
}
```

**UPDATE:**

```
$browserEventListener = function($event)
    {
        $browser = new \BrowserCheck\Service\BrowserCheck();
        if (!$browser->isCompatible())
        {
            $viewModel = new \Zend\View\Model\ViewModel();
            $viewModel->setTerminal(true);

            $request = $event->getRequest();
            $response = $event->getResponse();

            $viewModel->setTemplate('browser-check/index/index.phtml');

            //Replace the entire view
            $event->setViewModel($viewModel);
            $event->stopPropagation();
            $response->setStatusCode(200);
            return $viewModel;
        }
    };
$sharedEvents = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager()->getSharedManager();
$sharedEvents->attach('Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractController',
  array('dispatch','dispatch.error'), $browserEventListener, 100);
```

Comment: At which position is this module (*Browsercheck*) defined in your application config? Did you try to put it on first place?

Comment: I did put it at the first.. still the same issue.

Comment: OK, and what about trying the last position?

Comment: sorry. did that as well. same issue. The code works all the time except for 404 and exceptions. somehow they are taking preference over this and I am not understanding why.

Comment: Me neither since you put the code into your `onBoostrap()` method which should be handled before the routing. The `boostrap` event is triggered as first of all events and the methods `onBootstrap()` of all registered modules should be invoked first (though the order in which they are invoked is somehow unclear to me). Afterwards the `route` event is triggered which is where the `404` happens. Dunno about the PHP exception. Have you though about moving this special browser handling into the `index.php`? Just as an edge-case solution to try?

Comment: Ahaaa... I got it... You did put the code into the `onBootstrap()`, but you are registering it on `dispatch` event - try to register it on `route` with some high prio, e.g. `10000`.

Comment: If I duplicate this code in the bootstrap of my exception handling module, it works for pages where exceptions occur. The mystery now is when 404 errors occur when a controller doesn't exist, the 404 still takes preference over this

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you register your event listener on the `dispatch` event, which occurs after `bootstrap` and after `route` events. If the event listener triggered at `route` event cannot identify the route, you receive a `404` error page and the application lifecycle is terminated before any other `dispatch` event listener could be invoked.

In order to invoke your event listener before any routing is applied, you now have two options:

- either register your event listener on `bootstrap` event with lower prio (e.g. lower than `10000`)
- or to register it on `route` listener with some higher priority, `10` should be enough

According to [ZF2 doc page](http://www.framework.zend.com/manual/2.1/en/modules/zend.mvc.mvc-event.html#order-of-events), `onBoostrap()` module methods are called with priority `10000` and `onRoute()` methods of `\Zend\Mvc\ModuleRouteListener` and `\Zend\Mvc\RouteListener` are called with priority `1` (higher the number higher the priority).

EDIT:

You should be doing something like this:

```
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
{
    /* ... all the default stuff here ... */


    $this->registerBrowserCheckEvent($e);
}

private function registerBrowserCheckEvent(MvcEvent $e)
{
    $eventManager = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager();
    $browserEventListener = function ($event) {
        $browser = new \BrowserCheck\Service\BrowserCheck();
        if (!$browser->isCompatible()) {
            $viewModel = new \Zend\View\Model\ViewModel();
            $viewModel->setTerminal(true);

            $request = $event->getRequest();
            $response = $event->getResponse();

            $viewModel->setTemplate('browser-check/index/index.phtml');

            //Replace the entire view
            $event->setViewModel($viewModel);
            $event->stopPropagation();
            $response->setStatusCode(200);
            return $viewModel;
        }
    };

    $eventManager->attach(MvcEvent::EVENT_BOOTSTRAP, $browserEventListener, 100);
}
```

Also please notice that ZF2 uses PSR-2 (at least) and your code should follow this convention as well (mind the small differences between your code and mine).

Comment: Please see my update above. The updated code above is working when an exception occurs and 404 occurs on controller actions. However, it is not getting executed if a controller not found error occurs. Can you suggest how I can fix it?

Comment: @Jake You are targeting the `AbstractController` event manager; If the controller is not found then the `AbstractController::dispatch` would never be triggered. You should attach the listeners to the application service manager rather than the `SharedEventManager`.

Comment: @alexp can you provide an example?